# PHP Variable Instantiated in Constructor resetting to null

Tags: php, constructor, null, rss, simplexml

I'm writing a small RSS parser in PHP, I'm using simplexml, and I've come across a problem. I've created a class called ArticleFormatter, here it is

```
class ArticleFormatter {

    private $feedData;

    function __construct($feedUrl) {
        $feedData = simplexml_load_file($feedUrl);
    }

    function parse() {
        echo " \n begin parsing \n";
        $rawArticles = $feedData->channel[0];
        print_r($rawArticles);
        echo "\n";
        $currentArticle = $rawArticles->item[0];
        print_r($currentArticle);
        $articles = array();
        echo "\n starting loop \n";
        for($i = 0; !is_null($currentArticle); $i++) {
            echo "ran";
            array_push($articles, $currentArticle);
            $currentArticle = $rawArticles->item[$i + 1];
        }
        return $articles;
    }

}
```

Now here's the thing, I know that simplexml_load_file is returning a legitimate SimpleXMLElement, because when I put a print statement inside of the constructor, it prints out all kinds of xml elements, and, what's more, I know that $feedData->item[0] is a legitimate SimpleXMLElement, because I've also tried printing that in the constructor. Yet, when parse() is run as is, all that gets printed out is "begin parsing starting loop Array ( )" (the code that calls this function prints out the return value). Suggesting to me that, when the parse function runs, $feedData is somehow equal to NULL, and so the function returns nothing but an empty array. I'm sure that I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere, so any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: You cannot access $feedData in your method this way. You should access it as object property via $this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, if you want to call methods or use properties of the class you are in, you **always** have to use `$this`:

```
function __construct($feedUrl) {
    $this->feedData = simplexml_load_file($feedUrl);
}


function parse() {
        echo " \n begin parsing \n";
        $rawArticles = $this->feedData->channel[0];
        print_r($rawArticles);
        ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, so I was actually dealing with 3 entirely different variables here. I'll read more into variable scope. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
class ArticleFormatter {

    private $feedData;

    function __construct($feedUrl) {
        $this->feedData = simplexml_load_file($feedUrl);
    }

    function parse() {
        print_r($this->feedData);
    }
}
```

//try this and i believe you will know how to do next